# Asignar AWS Topic SNS a una alarma creada en otro stack de Cloudformation

Tags: aws, stack

Me surge una duda, tengo una larma que ya fue creada en otro stack de Cloudformation y ahora debo crear otro stack para asignarle dos propiedades mas `AlarmActions:` y `OKActions:` a estas alarmas.
Además no puedo hacer un change set en la plantilla inicial.

Mi pregunta es ¿Como debo realizar esto en la nueva plantilla?

Esta es parte de la plantilla inicial con la cual fueron creadas las alarmas.

```
  APIID01Alarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: "Error 4XX"
      AlarmActions:
      - !Ref SNSTopic
      MetricName: "4xx"
      Namespace: AWS/ApiGateway
      Statistic: Sum
      Period: '300'
      EvaluationPeriods: '1'
      Threshold: '20'
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      TreatMissingData: "notBreaching"
      Dimensions:
      - Name: ApiId
        Value: !Ref APIID
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es exportar ese recurso en el cloudformation donde se crea:

```
Outputs:
    SNSTopicToExport:
        Description: SNS Topic que nececesitas en otro cloudformation
        Value: !Ref "APIID01Alarm"
        Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-SNSTopic"
```

Los recursos que se exportan deben tener un identificador único para todos los stacks, por eso suele añadirse en el campo `Name` el nombre del stack actual.

Ya solo nos queda importar el recurso en otro stack.

Para no editar los cloudformation a mano, se suele añadir un parámetro de entrada para que se pueda introducir el nombre del stack del que vamos a depender:

```
Parameters:
    SNSTopicStackParameter:
        Type: String
        Description: Nombre del stack que contiene el SNS Topic que quieres reutilizar
```

Y ya solo nos queda importar el recurso donde corresponda:

```
UnaAlarma:
    type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
        AlarmActions:
            - Fn::ImportValue:
                !Sub "${SNSTopicStackParameter}-SNSTopic"
```